# Using konsole (kde) color schemes in gnome terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal, konsole

Is there a way to colorize the Gnome terminal in the way the konsole from KDE uses colors? I'd at least like to change the color for `user@name:~$`, because sometimes it gets pretty hard to read when everything is the same color.

Here are some examples of konsole I would like to emulate for gnome terminal:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the foreground and background colors of the text within the terminal itself, it is certainly possible. Those colors are produced by ANSI escape codes, which are not specific to either Konsole or gnome-terminal; they work on any terminal program that supports color at all. For a complete list of the codes, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Codes).

To actually use the color codes, you write a sequence of the form `\[\033[01;31m\]`. That example changes the text foreground color to bright red (`01` is bright, `31` is red) until it encounters another color change. To use a different color, change the 31 to any number from 30-37 (for foreground colors) or 40-47 (for background colors). As an example, my shell prompt is set by

```
export PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \[\033[01;37m\]\$\[\033[00m\] "
```

which gives me username@host in green, working directory in blue, and then a literal `$` in yellow. The `\[\033[00m\]` at the end is a reset code which clears whatever foreground/background colors have been set.

By the way, the actual color that, say, `31` corresponds to is normally red, but it can be changed. I know that Konsole allows you to set the ANSI color palette, I'm not sure if gnome-terminal has the same ability.

Comment: Yes, worked for gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

See also Gnome Terminal ➤ Edit ➤ Profiles... and `vi +/color ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Editing bashrc will work, I have to edit PS1= like David Zaslavsky said.